# Values on the bar-charts are crossing the grid

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart, nodes-near-coords

I am trying to put the values inside the grid for the charts, but as you can see from the output below, the values for data points cross the boundary (both left and right sides).

**My output:**

[image]

**Latex code:**

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc,xcolor={dvipsnames}]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
%\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{groupplot}[
group style={group size=3 by 1}, 
    width=0.33\textwidth, height=1cm,
    xmajorgrids = true,
    tick align = outside, xtick pos = left,
    scale only axis,
    x post scale=0.85,
    enlarge y limits=0.15,
    ytick distance=1,
%   
    xmin=0,xmax=100,
    ytick = data, yticklabels = {N=3,N=6, N=12,N=24},
    xtick={0,20,...,100},
    xticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\%},% <-- prints % sign after x tick value
    xticklabel style={font=\scriptsize},
    yticklabel style = {font=\scriptsize},
%    
    nodes near coords style={font=\scriptsize, 
                             yshift={ifthenelse(or(\plotnum == 5,\plotnum == 2),  8pt,8pt)}
                            }, % shift down the third and sixth node
%
    title style = {at={(0.5,-0.3)}, anchor=north},
    legend style={at={(0.5,1.05)}, anchor=south,
                  legend columns=4, font=\footnotesize,
                  cells={anchor=west},
                  /tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=0.5em}
                  }
                    ]
\nextgroupplot[title=(a) MADDPG,
    xbar stacked,
    bar width=3mm,
    y=8mm,
    nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}\%},
                ]
\addplot [color=black, fill=teal] coordinates{(34.73,1) (19.64,2) (9.47,3) (18.45,4) };
\addplot [color=black, fill=yellow] coordinates{(16.57,1) (39.97,2) (56.37,3) (18.45,4)};
\addplot [color=black, fill=olive] coordinates{(36.56,1) (37.27,2)(32.63,3) (18.45,4)};
\addplot [color=black, fill=orange] coordinates{(12.14,1) (3.12,2) (1.53,3) (18.45,4)};

\nextgroupplot[title=(b) MATD3,
    xbar stacked,
    bar width=3mm,
    y=8mm,
    nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}\%},
                ]
\addplot [color=black, fill=teal] coordinates{(38,1) (22,2) (20.00,3) (18.45,4) };
\addplot [color=black, fill=yellow] coordinates{(22,1) (36,2) (20.00,3) (18.45,4)};
\addplot [color=black, fill=olive] coordinates{(37,1) (40,2)(20.00,3) (18.45,4)};
\addplot [color=black, fill=orange] coordinates{(3,1) (2,2) (20.00,3) (18.45,4)};

    %\legend{Action selection, Environment Interactions,   Gradient synchronization},
    \legend{Action selection,   Environment interactions, Update all trainers,
                    Other Parts},
\nextgroupplot[title=(c) MASAC,
    xbar stacked,
    bar width=3mm,
    y=8mm,
    nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}\%},
                ]
\addplot [color=black, fill=teal] coordinates{(43,1) (31,2) (20.00,3) (18.45,4) };
\addplot [color=black, fill=yellow] coordinates{(21,1) (36,2) (20.00,3) (18.45,4)};
\addplot [color=black, fill=olive] coordinates{(33,1) (31,2)(20.00,3) (18.45,4)};
\addplot [color=black, fill=orange] coordinates{(3,1) (2,2) (20.00,3) (18.45,4)};

    \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}

\label{figure1}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

**Reference chart**

[image]

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes the values cross the boundaries. How would you like this to be resolved?

Comment: Hello, @hpekristiansen. I saw a chart from one of the paper. So, I just thought if there is any way by increasing the grid size or either by reducing the size of the values or any other approach. I also updated the question with the reference chart. If there is no solution for this, I do understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `red` in `coordinate style/.condition={x-0.5*rawx>95}{red, xshift=-4pt},`

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
group style={group size=3 by 1, horizontal sep=1.2cm}, 
xmajorgrids=true,
tick align=outside, xtick pos=left,
scale only axis,
x post scale=0.85,
enlarge y limits=0.18,
xmin=0, xmax=100,
xtick={0,20,...,100},
ytick=data, yticklabels={N=3,N=6, N=12,N=24},
xticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\%},
xticklabel style={font=\scriptsize},
yticklabel style={font=\scriptsize, xshift=3pt},
nodes near coords style={font=\scriptsize,  yshift=8pt},
legend style={at={(0.5,1.05)}, anchor=south, legend columns=4, font=\footnotesize, cells={anchor=west}},
xbar stacked,
/pgf/bar width=3mm,
y=8mm,
title style={at={(0.5,-0.3)}, anchor=north},
nodes near coords={\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/precision=0}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}\%},
%coordinate style/.condition={x-0.5*rawx<5}{red, xshift=4pt},
coordinate style/.condition={x-0.5*rawx>95}{red, xshift=-4pt},
]
\nextgroupplot[title=(a) MADDPG]
\addplot [color=black, fill=teal] coordinates{(34.73,1) (19.64,2) (9.47,3) (18.45,4) };
\addplot [color=black, fill=yellow] coordinates{(16.57,1) (39.97,2) (56.37,3) (18.45,4)};
\addplot [color=black, fill=olive] coordinates{(36.56,1) (37.27,2)(32.63,3) (18.45,4)};
\addplot [color=black, fill=orange] coordinates{(12.14,1) (3.12,2) (1.53,3) (18.45,4)};

\nextgroupplot[title=(b) MATD3]
\addplot [color=black, fill=teal] coordinates{(38,1) (22,2) (20.00,3) (18.45,4) };
\addplot [color=black, fill=yellow] coordinates{(22,1) (36,2) (20.00,3) (18.45,4)};
\addplot [color=black, fill=olive] coordinates{(37,1) (40,2)(20.00,3) (18.45,4)};
\addplot [color=black, fill=orange] coordinates{(3,1) (2,2) (20.00,3) (18.45,4)};
\legend{Action selection, Environment interactions, Update all trainers, Other Parts},

\nextgroupplot[title=(c) MASAC]
\addplot [color=black, fill=teal] coordinates{(43,1) (31,2) (20.00,3) (18.45,4) };
\addplot [color=black, fill=yellow] coordinates{(21,1) (36,2) (20.00,3) (18.45,4)};
\addplot [color=black, fill=olive] coordinates{(33,1) (31,2)(20.00,3) (18.45,4)};
\addplot [color=black, fill=orange] coordinates{(3,1) (2,2) (20.00,3) (18.45,4)};

\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Three x bar plots]